# How to use conditional statements in XMLTABLE

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, xmltable

I was wondering whether it is possible to use an if or conditional statement inside an Oracle XMLTABLE structure with XPATH. For design reasons I am restricted to use only xpath inside an XMLTABLE. I have used if statements in XQUERY which has worked fine in the past.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM emp, 
XMLTABLE ('*:Foo/*[contains(name(), "example")]' passing doc as "d" 
   COLUMNS
   Y varchar2(4000) PATH 'if (/*:Hotel) then ''Hotel'' else if (/*:Hostel) then ''HOSTEL'' else null' 
) AS X
```

This is the error message I get:

```
ORA-19109: RETURNING keyword expected
19109. 00000 -  "RETURNING keyword expected"
*Cause:    The keyword RETURNING was missing.
*Action:   Specify the RETURNING keyword.
Error at Line: 24 Column: 69
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems I needed to use quotation marks and not 2 single apostrophe's so this is now the correct way:

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM emp, 
XMLTABLE ('*:Foo/*[contains(name(), "example")]' passing doc as "d" 
   COLUMNS
   Y varchar2(4000) PATH 'if (/*:Hotel) then "Hotel" else if (/*:Hostel) then "HOSTEL" else null' 
) AS X
```